# NodeJs can not find function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I have a NodeJs project, and ***some*** imported libraries are not working properly, namely bookshelf and pg. This problem does not seem to be coming from the libraries, since they are 'official' packages available via npm.

Here's one snippet that's not working properly:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.connect('postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/myproject');
```

giving me the following error:

```
pg.connect();
TypeError: pg.connect is not a function
```

Although the function connect() obviously exists and should be accessed that way according to the documentation.

This also happens with bookshelf. If I try something like this:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'mypw',
    database : 'userdb',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  }
});
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'user'
})

bookshelf.plugin('registry');
module.exports = bookshelf;
```

The IDE tells me that `Model` can't be found if I hover over it with the curser, and if I try to create a new entry in the database with

```
new User({username: 'test',
           .... })
```

I get an error saying that

```
TypeError: User is not a constructor
```

Again, I have used the official documentation of the library bookshelf to create the last snippet.

I am also using express, hogan, bcrypt and they work perfectly fine.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you actually installed the `pg` and `knex` modules?

Comment: Hey, missing some detailes. How are you installing the libraries? are you using npm or yarn to install the packages? In the case of npm, did you check the librares are in node_modules folder?

Comment: If they are installed globally you need to be aware of the version of node being run by the IDE and that used to install...  If they are different the libraries will nit be found

Comment: `pg` and `knex` are both installed. I am using npm to install them. I am not installing them globally. They are present in the node_modules folder

Answer (score 6):

**About the problem of `connect` function:**

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/myproject";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

The `connect` function is declared in `Client`

Follow this link with more documentation about `node-postgres` package https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres